# ROBLOX Change leaderboard team by code

Tags: lua, roblox

I need to make a code that would change the team of a player.

Let's say I have Red Team and Blue Team.

Now I want to get a player to the Blue Team by code.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [Player](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Player) object have the property [TeamColor](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Player/TeamColor). When this color matches a [Team](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Team)'s [TeamColor](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Team/TeamColor) then the player is in that team.

If you simply want to change the `Player1`'s team to the `Red Team` you do:

```
game.Players.Player1.TeamColor = game.Teams["Blue Team"].TeamColor
```

Also to note is that the `TeamColor` is actually a [BrickColor](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=BrickColor), which means that you could hardcode the color (but that requires changes to the script if you change the BrickColor of a team, however if you hardcode the TeamColor, you can change the Team name without worries, which the code abow do not allow)

```
local TeamRed = Instance.new("Team")
TeamRed.Name = "Team Red"
TeamRed.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Bright red")
TeamRed.Parent = game:GetService("Teams")

-- Some other script

game.Players.Player1.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Bright red")
```

However i recommend making the Teams in the code where you later use them:

```
local TeamRed = Instance.new("Team")
TeamRed.Name = "Team Red"
TeamRed.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Bright red")
TeamRed.Parent = game:GetService("Teams")

local TeamBlue = Instance.new("Team")
TeamBlue.Name = "Team Blue"
TeamBlue.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Bright blue")
TeamBlue.Parent = game:GetService("Teams")

local some_clever_named_variable = true

game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(Player)
    Player.TeamColor = some_clever_named_variable and TeamRed.TeamColor or TeamBlue.TeamColor
    some_clever_named_variable = not some_clever_named_variable
end)
```

Comment: I have a folder called Teams in the Explorer(not in Workspace) and I can't change the team with this: `game.Players.Player1.TeamColor = game.Teams["Blue Team"].TeamColor` (The testing player name is Player1 so it's not that case)

Comment: @TomLenc, the `Teams` should not be an `Folder` but the service `Teams`, my last code would make two teams in the proper place, try it and you see how it works. The `Teams` service is specially inserted if you want to do it manualy instead, see [the wiki guide](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=How_do_I_add_Teams%3F)

Comment: Will adjusting the Player's TeamColor manually put them in the correct team then?

Comment: I first had to set player Neutral to false

Comment: yes it is :)
But now when I make a new SpawnLocation and set the same teamcolor, sometimes the player won't spawn on the spawnlocation..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84749/discussion-between-zombiespy-and-tom-lenc).